# Раздвоение блока на CSS3

Tags: css, css3, scss

Добрый день!
Подскажите как сделать раздвоение блока как на скрине? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
a{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:1rem;
  background:#276cae;
  border-top-left-radius:1rem;
  z-index:2;
}
a:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:1rem;
  left:-1rem;
  width:1rem;
  height:102rem;
  background:rgba(108, 151, 197, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius:1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius:1rem;
}
a:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:2rem;
  left:-2rem;
  width:2rem;
  height:100rem;
  background:rgba(108, 151, 197, 0.5);
  border-top-left-radius:1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius:1rem;
}
i{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  height:4px;
  width:50px;
  margin:5px 0;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span><i></i><i></i><i></i></span></a>
```